# Vue/Vuetify - Cannot get variables to display

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a front end in Vuetify and have a nodejs server with some data on it. When the page is created I run the async functions to fetch the data from the server and store it in the variables. I have a skeleton loader set up so the data has time to load, the problem is that when I store the data in the variables, it will not show up. My data looks like this,

```
data() {
  return {
    //holds data coming from server
      loading: false,
      makEosComputer: 0,
      makEosUserTotal: 0,
      makArchComputer: 0,
      cards: [
        {title: 'Eos Lab', os: 'Linux', roomno: 'idk', comps: this.makEosComputer},
        {title: 'Arch Lab', os: 'Linux', roomno: 'idk', comps: this.makArchComputer},
        {title: 'Data Comm Lab', os: 'Linux', roomno: 'idk', comps: this.makDataComputer}
      ],
```

and then I have an async function that grabs the data like this,

```
 methods: {
  async getEosComp() {
    this.loading = true
    collectDataService.getMakEosTotalComp()
    .then(data => {
      this.makEosComputer = data
      this.loading = false
    })
  },
```

the async methods are called in the created() section. Then in the html I attempt to put these values on screen like so.

```
   <p>Total Computers Online: {{card.comps}}</p>
```

If I change the declaration of the variable to makEosComputer: 10, then the 10 wont show up on screen, but if in cards array I change the comps: 10 then that will display. Why wont my variables show up on screen?

Comment: you are filling makEosComputer, while you are showing data from card ??

`   .then(data => {
      this.makEosComputer = data
      this.loading = false
    })`

where is cards data ?? or it's from vuex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding why it won't render, the return of `data()` it's what set pros so you can do `this.makEosComputer`, so until that doesn't return that pro doest exist, thus you can't use it in your def of `cards`

```
data() {
    return {
        makEosComputer: 10,
        cards: [
            {title: 'Eos Lab', os: 'Linux', roomno: 'idk', comps: null},
        ],
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.cards[0].comps = this.makEosComputer;
}
```

then `{{ cards[0].comps }}` will display `10`

Comment: when I try this I get "cannot read property "0" of undefined.

Comment: weird I just gave it a try and it's working, where are you getting the error? in `mounted()` or the _template_?